# 'Exception' with message 'Quote totals must be collected before this operation.'

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, discount, quote

I have create a programmatically order and set programmatically discount amount but i have getting error when submit order.
Here is exception message :

```
DEBUG (7): ====ex==exception 'Exception' with message 'Quote totals must be collected before this operation.' in /home/xyz/public_html/testing/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote.php:1861
Stack trace:
#0 /home/xyz/public_html/testing/app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php(326): Mage_Sales_Model_Quote->prepareRecurringPaymentProfiles()
#1 /home/xyz/public_html/testing/app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php(223): Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote->_submitRecurringPaymentProfiles()
#2 /home/xyz/public_html/testing/app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php(238): Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote->submitNominalItems()
#3 /home/xyz/public_html/testing/app/code/local/Assel/StoreOwners/controllers/SalesorderController.php(364): Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote->submitAll()
#4 /home/xyz/public_html/testing/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Assel_StoreOwners_SalesorderController->submitOrderAction()
#5 /home/xyz/public_html/testing/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('submitOrder')
#6 /home/xyz/public_html/testing/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#7 /home/xyz/public_html/testing/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#8 /home/xyz/public_html/testing/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#9 /home/xyz/public_html/testing/sellertesting.xyz.com/index.php(385): Mage::run('sellerwebsite', 'website')
#10 {main}
```

Please can anyone suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

please add your code to question 
i think you should do like this code

```
      $quote->setData($data);
      $quote->collectTotals()->save();
```